# Volta error: Could not create temporary directory

Tags: typescript, npm, volta

I am trying to download and install typescript globally through the `npm install -g typescript` command in my terminal. However, I get an error:

```
Volta error: Could not create temporary directory
in /Users/username/.volta/tmp/image/packages

Please ensure you have correct permissions to the Volta directory.
Error details written to /Users/username/.volta/log/volta-error-2022-07-06_21_40_34.962.log
```

I already have nodejs (v16.13.1) and npm (v8.1.2) installed on my computer.

Why is this error coming up and any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can open a PowerShell/CMD as an administrator (click right then run as admin) then run the command to install global package